# Can't run tmux although it's installed

Tags: bash, software-installation, executable

I compiled tmux from source on Ubuntu 12.04 and it is installed in `/usr/local/bin/tmux` by default.

However, when I type `tmux` in terminal I get the following message:

```
$ tmux
-bash: /usr/bin/tmux: No such file or directory
```

- How do I fix this? And how to install it in another location the next time?
- Is there any difference between putting it in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. I just needed to open a new bash session.

Just type "bash" in console and you're ready to go.